# Correcting the standard errors, when the second stage is a tobit regression

Tags: r

I am trying to implement [this bootstrap method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/instrumental-variable-tobit-in-r) for my data, but with more variables, to correct my standard errors. Somewhere I am messing up though (the original code is posted at the bottom)..

Cross-posted at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503698/correcting-the-standard-errors-when-the-second-stage-is-a-tobit-regression)

```
set.seed(2)

a    <- 2    # structural parameter of interest
b    <- 1    # strength of instrument
rho  <- 0.5  # degree of endogeneity

N    <- 1000
z    <- rnorm(N)
res1 <- rnorm(N)
res2 <- res1*rho + sqrt(1-rho*rho)*rnorm(N)
x    <- z*b + res1
ys   <- x*a + res2
d    <- (ys>0) #dummy variable
y    <- round(10-(d*ys))
random_variable <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)

library(data.table)
DT_1 <- data.frame(y,x,z, random_variable)
DT_2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015), Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C"), event = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), win_or_lose = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
DT_1 <- setDT(DT_1)
DT_2 <- setDT(DT_2)
DT_2 <- rbind(DT_2 , DT_2 [rep(1:50, 19), ])
sandbox <- cbind(DT_1, DT_2)
```

I am trying to implement the bootstrap method as follows:

```
# z = exogenous (IV)
# random_variable  = exogenous (IV)
# year = exogenous
```

The first stage is an ols.

```
ols <- lm(x ~ z + random_variable + year, data=sandbox);print(summary(ols))
```

The second stage is a tobit:

```
inconsistent.tobit <- censReg(y~x)
summary(inconsistent.tobit)

reduced.form <- ols
summary(reduced.form)


consistent.tobit <- censReg(y~fitted(reduced.form)+residuals(reduced.form))
summary(consistent.tobit)


# I'd like bootstrapped standard errors, please!

tobit_2siv_coef <- function(data, indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  reduced.form <- ols
  consistent.tobit <- censReg(d[,"y"]~fitted(reduced.form)+residuals(reduced.form))
  return(summary(consistent.tobit)$estimate["fitted(reduced.form)",1])
}

boot.results <- boot(data=sandbox, statistic=tobit_2siv_coef, R=100)
boot.results
```

In my actual data, I did not get the same estimate, in the example data I get the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = d[, "y"] ~ fitted(reduced.form) +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'd[, "y"]'
```

## Original example ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/instrumental-variable-tobit-in-r))

```
require(censReg)
require(boot)

a    <- 2    # structural parameter of interest
b    <- 1    # strength of instrument
rho  <- 0.5  # degree of endogeneity

N    <- 1000
z    <- rnorm(N)
res1 <- rnorm(N)
res2 <- res1*rho + sqrt(1-rho*rho)*rnorm(N)
x    <- z*b + res1
ys   <- x*a + res2
d    <- (ys>0) #dummy variable
y    <- d*ys

inconsistent.tobit <- censReg(y~x)
summary(inconsistent.tobit)

reduced.form <- lm(x~z)
summary(reduced.form)


consistent.tobit <- censReg(y~fitted(reduced.form)+residuals(reduced.form))
summary(consistent.tobit)


# I'd like bootstrapped standard errors, please!
my.data <- data.frame(y,x,z)
tobit_2siv_coef <- function(data,indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  reduced.form <- lm(x~z,data=d)
  consistent.tobit <- censReg(d[,"y"]~fitted(reduced.form)+residuals(reduced.form))
  return(summary(consistent.tobit)$estimate["fitted(reduced.form)",1])
}

boot.results <- boot(data=my.data,statistic=tobit_2siv_coef,R=100)
boot.results
```

## EDIT - AER::TOBIT version

```
  reduced.form <- lm(x ~ z + random_variable + year, data=x)
  consistent.tobit <<- AER::tobit(y ~ fitted(reduced.form) + residuals(reduced.form), left=0, right=100, data=dataset)

  bootstrap_se <- function(x) {
    reduced.form <- first_stage_ols
    AER::tobit(y ~ fitted(reduced.form) + residuals(reduced.form), left=0, right=100, data=dataset)$estimate
    # second_stage_tobit_b$estimate
  }
  library(AER::tobit)
  R <- 100
  res <- t(replicate(R, bootstrap_se(dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), nrow(dataset), replace=T), ])))
  # To scrape out a summary, the matrixStats package is most convenient.
  library(matrixStats)
  b <- consistent.tobit$coefficients
  b <- append(b, consistent.tobit[["icoef"]][["Log(scale)"]])
  SE <- colSds(res)
  z <- consistent.tobit$coefficients/SE
  p <- 2 * pt(-abs(z), df = Inf)
  ci <- colQuantiles(res, probs=c(.025, .975))
  res <<- signif(cbind(b, SE, z, p, ci), 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `boot`, but basically you could put the code into a `FUN`ction and sample the observations using `sample` with `replace=TRUE` in a `replicate`.

```
library(AER)
reduced.form <- lm(x ~ z + random_variable + year, data=sandbox)
consistent.tobit <- tobit(y ~ fitted(reduced.form) + residuals(reduced.form), 
                          left=0, right=100, data=sandbox)

FUN <- function(x) {
  reduced.form <- lm(x ~ z + random_variable + year, data=x)
  fit <- tobit(y ~ fitted(reduced.form) + residuals(reduced.form), data=x)
  c(fit$coefficients, logSigma=log(fit$scale))
}

set.seed(42)
R <- 200
bs <- t(replicate(R, FUN(sandbox[sample(nrow(sandbox), nrow(sandbox), replace=T), ])))
```

To scrape out a summary, the `matrixStats` package is most convenient.

```
library(matrixStats)
b <- c(consistent.tobit$coefficients, logSigma=log(consistent.tobit$scale))
SE <- colSds(bs)
z <- b/SE
p <- 2 * pt(-abs(z), df = Inf)
ci <- colQuantiles(bs, probs=c(.025, .975))
res <- signif(cbind(b, SE, z, p, ci), 4)
res
#                               b      SE      z          p    2.5%   97.5%
#   (Intercept)            8.6470 0.04127 209.50  0.000e+00  8.5630  8.7190
# fitted(reduced.form)    -1.0600 0.04261 -24.86 1.890e-136 -1.1400 -0.9772
# residuals(reduced.form) -1.2960 0.05493 -23.59 4.958e-123 -1.3830 -1.1740
# logSigma                 0.1589 0.02665   5.96  2.518e-09  0.1067  0.2049
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `boot` was (indeed) only the means to an end (correcting the standard errors). Going to incorporate this in my iv-function now:) Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, one more question. Iis there an intuitive explanation why this works and what the role or the variable `R` is in that respect?

Comment: @Tom Sure, 1. in each replication we generate a new sample which reuses the original distribution, thus we obtain a valid variance (recommended reading: [*Stine, 1989*](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0049124189018002003)), 2. `R` defines just the number of replications, I like to define it outside `replicate` for better visibility.

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot. I noticed that `ci` is not created as one of the variables, I get (`Error in cbind(b, SE, z, p, ci) : object 'ci' not found`). I tried to see if it was in `res` but I cannot find it.

Comment: @Tom BTW Do the censorship of DV and IV in your model have switched? I'm surprised!

Comment: Nope, two separate papers :D I'm working a lot with survey data, so everything is censored ;)

Comment: I was about to post a complete example of my calculation and your test, but I just noticed that I am getting a different result from the one that you posted when using your code. Is there anything that could be version specific, or could there be another copy-paste issue?

Comment: @Tom Actually there was just a `set.seed()` missing to make it reproducible for you. See Update.

Comment: Thanks! I still could not get the results right, so I posted another question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503748/manual-calculation-an-instrumental-variable-with-a-tobit-distribution-in-the-2nd. I think I will have to give up for today:)

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried to convert your solution for `censReg` to `AER::tobit` (see EDIT) because it has more options. I think I did a pretty decent job, but somehow `SE` ends up with a variable less than intended. As `SE` is based on the first `res` I do not really understand why this happen. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh, I think it happens because the `logsigma` is somewhere else in `AER::tobit`. I figured out how to add it to `b`, but not to `SE`.

Comment: @ Jay, in case you are interested ;) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505152/limited-reponse-instrumented-variable