# Correcting (or bootstrapping) the standard errors for a two stage glm (subscript out of bounds)

Tags: r, glm, statistics-bootstrap

Cross posted on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518719/correcting-or-bootstrapping-the-standard-errrors-for-a-two-stage-glm).

I am trying to bootstrap my results for a variation of the 2SLS approach (2SRI), based on [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/instrumental-variable-tobit-in-r). For some reason, the bootstrap does not produce any results.

```
library(sure) # for residual function and sample data sets
library(MASS) # for polr function
rm(df1)
df1 <- df1
df1$x2 <- df2$y
df1$x3 <- df2$x
df1$y <- df3$x/10
fit.polr <- polr(x2 ~ x + x3, data = df1, method = "probit")

# BOOTSTRAPPING
library(boot)
glm_2siv_coef <- function(data,indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  stage_1 <- polr(x2 ~ x + x3, Hess=TRUE, data=d)
  stage_2 <- glm(y ~ x + x2 + x3 + resids(stage_1),
  family = "quasibinomial", data=d)
  return(summary(stage_2)$estimate["x2",1])
}

boot.results <- boot(data=df1,statistic=glm_2siv_coef,R=1)
boot.results
```

Produces: `Error in boot.out$t[, index] : subscript out of bounds`

When I look at boot.results, the `t0` and `t` values are empty, and they are not supposed to be.

Could anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Okay, I will keep it in mind. I cross posted because it is part code, part statistics. I do not do that often, but here I am pretty sure the solutions will be related. And I thought the general  rule was to mention cross posting explicitly. I also adapted the questions to match the respective sites.

Comment: Could you provide `df1`?

Comment: df1 should be provided by the `sure` package. It does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback : I missed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `x2` is an ordinal variable, so when you call it in the glm, you will have n-1 coefficients, because the default contrast for ordinal dependent variable is contrast.poly, and it transform it into its quadratic terms (see more [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/polynomial-contrasts-for-regression)):

```
glm(y ~ x + x2 + x3 ,data=df1)

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x + x2 + x3, data = df1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x         x2.L         x2.Q         x2.C         x2^4  
 -5.561e-16    1.000e-01    1.156e-17   -1.352e-18   -2.349e-17   -2.255e-17  
         x3  
 -5.294e-18
```

The code you got from the link is a summary on another R object, but for `glm`, if you only need the coefficients, there's no harm in returning all the coefficients:

```
glm_2siv_coef <- function(data,indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  stage_1 <- polr(x2 ~ x + x3, Hess=TRUE, data=d)
  stage_2 <- glm(y ~ x + x2 + x3 + resids(stage_1),
                 family = "quasibinomial", data=d)
  coefficients(stage_2)
}
boot.results <- boot(data=df1, statistic=glm_2siv_coef, R=10)
```

You can look the the bootstrap results like this:

```
mat = boot.results$t
colnames(mat) = names(glm_2siv_coef(df1,1:nrow(df1)))

head(mat)
     (Intercept)         x         x2.L        x2.Q         x2.C          x2^4
[1,]   -2.298085 0.4555501 -0.019243084 -0.01222671  0.003672487  0.0009351758
[2,]   -2.287667 0.4527313  0.024065483 -0.01124712  0.005012817  0.0028092668
[3,]   -2.297377 0.4543327  0.042194399 -0.02041060  0.007764768 -0.0025922548
[4,]   -2.301298 0.4565478  0.009459445 -0.01958682  0.000313143 -0.0058883027
[5,]   -2.296350 0.4544981 -0.010628593 -0.01141557 -0.005545030 -0.0030184318
[6,]   -2.297909 0.4537336  0.004486517 -0.01576363  0.016248869 -0.0005906523
               x3 resids(stage_1)
[1,] 9.114145e-04    0.0015985900
[2,] 1.187623e-03   -0.0020883363
[3,] 1.442589e-03   -0.0027610646
[4,] 9.258333e-05   -0.0021435513
[5,] 1.963208e-03    0.0005474028
[6,] 2.218785e-03    0.0014221113
```

The x2 related ones will be:

```
mat[,2:5]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand the model itself, but as far as I can see, this is not an issue with the model.

The problem is that the function you pass to `boot` is not returning anything. There are two reasons for this: First, there is no element in the summary of a `glm` that is called estimate, so `summary(stage_2)$estimate` is `NULL`. Second, even if the first problem didn't exist, there is no coefficient that has the name `"x2"`. This is because x2 is an ordered factor, which is internally turned into dummies.

You can adjust your code as follows:

```
glm_2siv_coef <- function(data,indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  stage_1 <- polr(x2 ~ x + x3, Hess=TRUE, data=d)
  stage_2 <- glm(y ~ x + x2 + x3 + resids(stage_1),
                 family = "quasibinomial", data=d)
  return(stage_2$coefficients)
}
boot.results <- boot(data=df1, statistic=glm_2siv_coef, R=100)
boot.results
```

You will need to decide for yourself which estimates are of interest to you, but this gives you bootstrap SEs for all your coefficients. Also note that I increased `R` to 100, because a single bootstrap sample doesn't make any sense. I kept it low for illustrative purposes, so you should consider increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595081/correcting-the-standard-errors-when-the-second-stage-is-a-tobit-regression), answer by @jay.sf.

```
set.seed(2)
sandbox$Group <- as.factor(sandbox$Group)
reduced.form <- polr(Group ~ z + random_variable + year, data=sandbox)
consistent.glm <- glm(y ~ Group + resids(reduced.form) + random_variable + year, family="quasibinomial", data=sandbox)

FUN <- function(x) {
  reduced.form <-  polr(Group ~ z + random_variable + year, data=x)
  fit <- glm(y ~ Group + resids(reduced.form) + random_variable + year,family="quasibinomial", data=x)
  fit$coefficients
}

set.seed(42)
R <- 200
bs <- t(replicate(R, FUN(sandbox[sample(nrow(sandbox), nrow(sandbox), replace=T), ])))

# To scrape out a summary, the matrixStats package is most convenient.

library(matrixStats)
b <- consistent.glm$coefficients
SE <- colSds(bs)
z <- b/SE
p <- 2 * pt(-abs(z), df = Inf)
ci <- colQuantiles(bs, probs=c(.025, .975))
res <- signif(cbind(b, SE, z, p, ci), 4)
res
```

## DATA

```
a    <- 2    # structural parameter of interest
b    <- 1    # strength of instrument
rho  <- 0.5  # degree of endogeneity

N    <- 1000
z    <- rnorm(N)
res1 <- rnorm(N)
res2 <- res1*rho + sqrt(1-rho*rho)*rnorm(N)
x    <- z*b + res1
ys   <- x*a + res2
d    <- (ys>0) #dummy variable
y    <- (10-(d*ys))/10
random_variable <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)

library(data.table)
DT_1 <- data.frame(y,x,z, random_variable)
DT_2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
                              13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
                              29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
                              45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
                                                                1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
                                                                2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
                                                                2005, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
                                                                2010, 2010, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                                                                2015), Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
                                                                                 "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
                                                                                 "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
                                                                                 "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                                                                 "C", "C"), event = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), win_or_lose = c(-1, 
                                                                                                                                                                    -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                    -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame"))
DT_1 <- setDT(DT_1)
DT_2 <- setDT(DT_2)
DT_2 <- rbind(DT_2 , DT_2 [rep(1:50, 19), ])
sandbox <- cbind(DT_1, DT_2)
sandbox <- setDT(sandbox)[y<0, y:=0]
```

Comment: I think this likely should be an edit to the question, rather than an answer. Really it's a question, "is this code correct'?

Comment: Removed the question part as it seems to be exactly what the others were doing.